# React + Formik + Papaparse: cannot access updated state value and instead get undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik, yup, papaparse

I am trying to create a multi-step form using React + Formik + Yup, I am done with most of the logic but this one part where I am supposed to process a csv file. I created a separate `CSVFileUploadField` component and used the `useField()` hook of `Formik`.

Formik nor Yup validate file data. I need to first ensure that the csv file uploaded by the user is valid and does not contain any weird formatting issues. I am using `papaparse` to parse the file, and I am able to detect errors and update the states. I intend to use this error field to determine whether the file can be validated further (e.g. checking for the number of rows and columns), but the `csvFileError` state is always undefined. Any hints/help is much appreciated.

`CSVFileUploadField.tsx`

```
import { useField } from "formik";
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";
/* ...truncated import */

function CSVFileUploadField({ color: _, ...props }: TCSVFileUploadField) {
  const [field, { error, value }, { setValue, setError }] = useField(props);
  const dispatch: Dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [csvFileError, setCsvFileError] = useState<string>(undefined);
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState<string>("");
  const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState<unknown[]>([]);
  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const classes = useStyle();

  // if the user goes to another part of the form and comes back, need to reinitialize the filename
  useEffect(() => {
    setFileName((previousValue) => (value ? value.name : "No file selected"));
  }, [value]);

  const synchronizeErrors = (message: string) => {
    setError(message); // form field error, but this gets overriden by further yup validation
    setCsvFileError((prevMessage) => message); // component state
    dispatch(taskFileErrors(message)); // redux state which is used to disable Next/Submit button in case of error
  };

  const processChunk = function ({ data, errors, meta }, parser) {
    // this is supposed to callback after reading every 1 MB data
    if (csvFileError) {
      parser.abort();
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      // just use the first parsing error
      synchronizeErrors(errors[0].message);
    } else {
      setCsvData((previousData) => {
        let newData = previousData;
        data.forEach((row) => newData.push(row));
        return newData;
      });
    }
  };

  const parseCsv = (file: File) => {
    const papaParseOptions: Papa.ParseConfig = {
      chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1, // 1 MB
      chunk: processChunk,
    };

    Papa.parse(file, papaParseOptions);
  };

  const handleFileChange = function (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  ) {
    const fileObj = event.target.files[0];

    if (fileObj) {
      // // clear any previous errors
      synchronizeErrors(undefined);
      setValue(fileObj);
      setFileName((previousName) => fileObj.name);
      parseCsv(fileObj);          // this is supposed to update the error states
      console.log(csvFileError);  // <-- this is always undefined, even with setTimeout(() => console.log(csvFileError), 5000)
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormControl error={!!error} className={classes.formControl}>
      <FormLabel htmlFor={field.name}>{props.label}</FormLabel>
      <input
        name={field.name}
        onChange={handleFileChange}
        {...props}
        accept={props.accept || ".csv, .tsv"}
        id={field.name}
        type="file"
        ref={fileInputRef}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
      <Box mt={2} display="flex" alignItems="center">
        <Button
          onClick={(_) => {
            fileInputRef.current.click();
          }}
          className={classes.button}
        >
          Choose CSV File
        </Button>
        <Typography className={classes.fileNameLabel}>{fileName}</Typography>
      </Box>

      {(error || csvFileError) && (
        <FormHelperText error={!!error || !!csvFileError}>
          {error || csvFileError}
        </FormHelperText>
      )}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default CSVFileUploadField;
```

EDIT:

I created a simplified codesandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-dust-6oo7m?file=/src/App.tsx). Look into the console after uploading a csv file that is malformed. The error is rendered as HTML but it is undefined in the console. I want to use the error to decide whether I want to further validate this file against some other condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my monkey brain had forgotten about stale states.

- If you are running a code that is "browser-only", the component states will be stale values. This type of code should be inside `useEffect()`.
- If you have code that will actually render something to the DOM using the state, you will get the correct value there.

In my case, parsing the CSV file is a browser only task. So, I had to change it up a bit.

```
function CSVFileUploadField({ color: _, ...props }: TCSVFileUploadField) {
  const [field, { error, value }, { setValue, setError }] = useField(props);

  const dispatch: Dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [csvFileError, setCsvFileError] = useState<string>(undefined);
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState<string>("");
  const [fileReading, setFileReading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [numRows, setNumRows] = useState<number>(0);
  const [numCols, setNumCols] = useState<number>(0);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<number>(0);

  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const classes = useStyle();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFileName((previousValue) => (value ? value.name : "No file selected"));
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // once file reading has ended, reset progress
    if (!fileReading) {
      setProgress(0);
    }

    // once reading is done we have concrete values
    if (value && numRows > 0 && numCols > 0 && !error && !csvFileError) {
      // no errors, send the row and column numbers to redux to use them in the next step of form
      dispatch(taskFileSelected(numRows, numCols));
    }
  }, [fileReading]);

  const synchronizeErrors = (message: string) => {
    setError(message); // form field error, but this gets overriden by further yup validation
    setCsvFileError((prevMessage) => message); // component state
    dispatch(taskFileErrors(message)); // redux state which is used to disable Next/Submit button in case of error
  };

  const parseCsv = (fileObj: File) => {
    const fileSize = fileObj.size;

    const parseConfig: Papa.ParseConfig = {
      worker: true, // use worker thread
      chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 15, // 15 MB
      chunk: ({ data, errors, meta }, parser) => {
        if (errors.length > 0) {
          synchronizeErrors(errors[0].message);
        } else {
          setNumRows((prevValue) => prevValue + data.length);
          setNumCols(data[0].length);
          setProgress((prevValue) =>
            Math.round((meta.cursor / fileSize) * 100),
          );
        }
      },
      complete: (results, fileObj) => {
        setFileReading((prevValue) => false);
      },
    };

    // when using worker, parse function is async
    // https://www.papaparse.com/faq#workers
    Papa.parse(fileObj, parseConfig);
  };

  const handleFileChange = function (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  ) {
    const fileObj = event.target.files[0];

    if (fileObj) {
      // clear any previous errors
      synchronizeErrors(undefined);
      // reset state
      setNumCols(0);
      setNumRows(0);

      setValue(fileObj);
      setFileName((previousName) => fileObj.name);

      setFileReading((prevValue) => true);
      parseCsv(fileObj);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormControl error={!!error} className={classes.formControl}>
      <FormLabel htmlFor={field.name}>{props.label}</FormLabel>
      <input
        name={field.name}
        onChange={handleFileChange}
        {...props}
        accept={props.accept || ".csv, .tsv"}
        id={field.name}
        type="file"
        ref={fileInputRef}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
      <Box mt={2} display="flex" alignItems="center">
        <Button
          onClick={(_) => {
            fileInputRef.current.click();
          }}
          className={classes.button}
        >
          Choose CSV File
        </Button>
        <Typography className={classes.fileNameLabel}>{fileName}</Typography>
      </Box>

      {fileReading && <LinearProgressBarWithLabel value={progress} />}

      {(error || csvFileError) && (
        <FormHelperText error={!!error || !!csvFileError}>
          {error || csvFileError}
        </FormHelperText>
      )}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default CSVFileUploadField;
```

I ended up adding a Progress Bar too, so, yay!.

On a separate note, I will probably end up refactoring this with `useReducer()`, simply because there are too many interrelated states.